# ¿Cual es el evento que necesito para hacer que se mueva el boton cuando acerco el mouse?

Tags: c#

Quiero hacer algo similar a lo que sale en este video.
https://www.facebook.com/elartedelaprogramacion/videos/459727254938964/

Comment: En la página de SO en inglés tienes una pregunta que puede orientarte en la manera de hacerlo [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position). 
 En resumen, javascript + evento onmousemove + variables clientX y clientY del evento

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. En este caso, por ejemplo, es importante si estas usando windows forms, wpf, asp....

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no hay un problema que se pueda reproducir. Entonces se basa en opiniones.

Answer (score 1):

El evento que debes capturar es el evento MouseMove del propio formulario.
Una vez hecho esto puedes calcular la distancia hacia el botón y moverlo a una nueva posición.

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Coordenadas X,Y centro botón.
            double btnX, btnY;

            btnX = button1.Location.X + button1.Size.Width / 2;
            btnY = button1.Location.Y + button1.Size.Height / 2;

            //Cálculo de distancia desde la posición del puntero al centro del botón.
            var distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(btnX - e.X, 2) + Math.Pow(btnY - e.Y, 2));

            //Distancia del puntero al botón en la que quieres que se mueva
            var maxDistance = 80;

            if ((int)distance < maxDistance)
            {
                Form1 form = (Form1)sender;

                //Coordenadas máximas en las que se puede localizar el botón
                var maxX = form.Width - button1.Size.Width;
                var maxY = form.Height - button1.Size.Height - 20;

                Random r = new Random();

                int nextX = r.Next(0, maxX);
                int nextY = r.Next(0, maxY);

                //Nueva posición
                button1.Location = new Point(nextX, nextY);
            }
        }
```

En mi ejemplo hay que tener en cuenta que la distancia se calcula respecto al centro del botón y no sobre los bordes, pero creo que es un buen punto para empezar ;)

Edit: Otro punto a tener en cuenta es que esto sólo funcionará si el ratón se mueve directamente sobre el formulario, y no sobre otro tipo de elemento (Panel, otro botón...).

Answer (score 0):

No es posible detectar el movimiento de acercamiento del raton al boton. Solo se puede detectar cuando se interactua con él.

Mi sugerencia sería el evento MouseHover.

Comment: Considera añadir esto como comentario, dado que es una sugerencia, o agregar algún código que ejemplifique como se realizaría usando MouseHover.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba esto para ver si te funciona

```js
function move(x) {
// console.log(x.clientHeight);
  var factor = 0.87;
  var posx = (Math.random() * (450 * factor)).toFixed();
  var posy = (Math.random() * (250 * factor)).toFixed();
  x.style.top = `${posy}px`;
  x.style.left = `${posx}px`;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 500; height: 300px; background: red;">
<button onmouseenter="move(this)" border="0" style="position: relative; width: 50px; height: 50px" >NO</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Estas ejecutando la función `move()` dos veces, creando un efecto extraño ya que se ve una doble transición. Podrías quitar el `onmouseleave`.

Comment: Por otro lado, la pregunta está en español, el sitio es en español..por que respondes en ingles?